# how to make a view that is pushed by another view when a button is clicked (keep both)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, master-detail

Initially there is a tab that contains a button at the top of the screen, and under it there is an initial/welcoming view.

when the button is pressed, the top tab shouldn't change. but another view will appear and push the welcoming view hiding a piece of it. Finally the tab is at top(taking 1024) ..  under it the width of the screen is shared between the welcoming view (taking 1024 / 2 ) and the new view (taking 1024 / 2 ).

How can this animation be implemented, taking into account that a part of the welcoming screen still needs to be visible.
(the transition/animation needed, looks like that caused by pushing "Show or Hide event library" in the iMovie app in OSX )

sorry if the question was naive as it's my first step in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to be using is Container Views

There is a great WWDC session that has a segment on using Container Views:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: It's very trivial so sorry. i have implemented it successfully using UIscrollView that contains the two views and changing the visible frame switch between them.